# Vue template rendered before onMounted

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have a simple Vue app with [Bulma Navbar](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/) and simle component. I'm using Firebase for authentication. App.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from "vue-router";
import NavBar from "@/components/Navbar.vue"
</script>

<template>
    <NavBar />
    <RouterView />
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@import 'bulma/css/bulma.min.css';
</style>
```

The problem is my Navbar is rendered prior to checking user status. As a result, the user is logged in but Navbar renders as if user was not logged in.

Here's how the Navbar looks with user not logged - Login and Sign up available:

Template uses flags and `v-if` to render elements:

```
        <a v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="navbar-item">
            <RouterLink to="/login" @click="burgerActive = 0">Login
            </RouterLink>
        </a>
        <a v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="navbar-item">
            <RouterLink to="/signup" @click="burgerActive = 0">Sign up</RouterLink>
        </a>
```

Flags are set using `onMounted` hook.

The problem is, the template is rendered before user flags are set. I tried debugging, and here's what I've got by placing some logging like:

```
onMounted(() => {
    console.log('1: entered onMounted', isLoggedIn.value, isAdmin.value)
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        console.log('2: onAuthStateChanged invoked')
        if (user) {
            isLoggedIn = true
            userName = user.displayName
            user.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
                isAdmin = idTokenResult.claims.admin
                console.log('3: user flags set', isLoggedIn.value, isAdmin.value)
            })
        } else {
            isLoggedIn = false
            isAdmin = false
        }
    })
    console.log('4: after onAuthStateChanged', isLoggedIn.value, isAdmin.value)
})
```

My understanding and expectation is that on mount, the authentication happens, flags are set, and template is rendered. What I get in the console output proves me wrong:

[image]

The result is that Navbar renders as if user was not logged in. But only upon page load.

How do I know that in fact user IS logged in? My user-dependent content renders properly.

And if I click any Navbar button, it re-renders propery, with `Login` and `Sign up` elements hidden.

What am I missing here?

Comment: unless its ssr and/or you set into a store or state the users current isLoggedIn before anything rendered you will get the switching, especially in mounted over created. if that's not possible then your need a global flag (which shows a loading state or minimal layout) you can toggle true after evaluating isLoggedIn etc

Comment: THANKS! Silly me - updating the assignment to `isAdmin.value = false` fixed my issues! Please leave an answer so I could mark in correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isLoggedIn = false` is a mistake here. The variables should never be reassigned in a component if they are intended to be reactive. There's no way how this kind of reactivity could be implemented in JS, not specifically in Vue. It's always object property that needs to be changed.

A ref should be `const` in order to avoid accidental reassignments:

```
const isLoggedIn = ref(false);
...
isLoggedIn.value = true;
```

This applies only to script part of the component and not template, refs are unwrapped in a template by Vue compiler.